# Error with javascript 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I am getting this error when I look at the javascript console 
POST (url of website) GetUserPass 500 (Internal Server Error).

A popup also says that there is an unexpected token > 
I am guessing that these two things are related so does anyone know anything about them or have they seen this before?

Here is the javascript code. The project is built in visual studio 2013.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/plugins/data-tables/jquery.dataTables.datesorting.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mvData = null;
        var mvTable;

        function GetDataSuccess(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $("#divMessage").html("").hide();
            $("#userPassTable").show();
            mvData = data.d;
            mvTable.fnClearTable();
            mvTable.fnAddData(data.d);
        }

        function GetDataError(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            try {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                $("#divMessage").html("An error occured: " + obj.Message + "<br>Exception Type: " + obj.ExceptionType).show();
            }
            catch (ex) { alert(ex.message); }
        }

        function logBodyOnLoad() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "UserPass.aspx/GetUserPass",
                data: JSON.stringify({}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: GetDataSuccess,
                error: GetDataError
            });

            mvTable = $('#userPassTable').dataTable(
            {
                "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    /* Need to redo the counters if filtered or sorted */
                    //     if (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) {
                    //        for (var i = 0, iLen = oSettings.aiDisplay.length; i < iLen; i++) {
                    //            $('td:eq(0)', oSettings.aoData[oSettings.aiDisplay[i]].nTr).html(i + 1);
                    //        }
                    //     }
                },
                "aoColumns":
                [
                    { "sTitle": "Vendor", sClass: "left_align" },
                    { "sTitle": "Username", sClass: "left_align" },
                    { "sTitle": "Password", sClass: "left_align" }
                ],
                "iDisplayLength": 1000,
                "aaData": [["", "", ""]],
                bPaginate: false,
                bFilter: true,
                bSort: false,
                bJQueryUI: true,
                bAutoWidth: false
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(logBodyOnLoad);
    </script>
```

Comment: There's an error in your `UserPass.aspx/GetUserPass` service. It has not much to do with JS, unless you simply aren't passing the correct data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am wondering if the "....aspx/GetUserPass" the slashed portion is causing this problem - sure it should not be a query string value?

This is a server-side error, which means you need to check your error logs on the server to see what is going on. If you don't have logging enabled (recommend ELMAH, very easy to plug in via NuGet) then two ways you can see what is going on:

1 - If you don't have additional data you are posting to the page, then the easiest is to just  browse to the page by itself, localhost:xxx/UserPass.aspx/GetUserPass

2 - If you do have unique data you are posting and need to see the results with that specific data, then use Chrome - open the debugger tools (F12) take a look at the Network tab and it will show the request to the server, select it and click the "response" tab to see the detail it spits out. Should be the ASP.NET error HTML when you can parse through and hopefully help figure out what is going on.

Hope this helps get you further down the road!